# nginx with http_perl_module doesn't execute perl scripts just downloads them

Tags: macos, perl, nginx

On my Mac OSX 10.7.4 with Perlbrew's Perl-5.16.0 I have this **nginx.conf**:

```
server {
   listen 1234;
   server_name MyPHPPerlServer;
   root "/Library/WebServer/servdir"; 

location / {
fancyindex on;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
         fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
         fastcgi_index index.php;
         fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
         include fastcgi_params;
         }

location ~ \.pl$ {
         try_files $uri =404;
         gzip off;
     #fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:8999;
         fastcgi_index index.pl;
         fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
         include fastcgi_params;
         } 
}
```

For this configuration to run the PHP scripts, I compiled and ran  `php-fpm`, and it runs PHP fine now.

To run the Perl scripts, I compiled nginx with
`./configure --add-module=../ngx-fancyindex --with-http_perl_module` and nginx runs fine with this configuration but when I browse to `http://localhost:1234/index.pl` it doesn't execute the Perl script, it just downloads it.

As a check, I shut down the nginx and start Apache with the **cgi_module** on and it runs the index.pl perfectly.

What should I do to make nginx run the Perl scripts? Thank you.

Comment: You don't use any http_perl_module features???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scripts are being sent to the browser because that's the default manner in which request files are handled, and you don't override this (say by using `fastcgi_pass`). Please follow the [instructions](http://nginxlibrary.com/perl-fastcgi/).

Comment: If I enable that line, it gives: 502 Bad Gateway so I disabled that line.

Comment: Is your FCGI daemon running? Is it listening at `127.0.0.1:8999`? Or did you stop halfway through the [instructions](http://nginxlibrary.com/perl-fastcgi/). Or if the daemon is running, it could be that your script isn't sending a response (in which case you should check the fcgi damon's error log).

Comment: I tried to run FCGI daemon by entering ./perl-fcgi start but it returned: Can't load '/Users/<shortened>/darwin-2level/auto/FCGI/FCGI.bundle' for module FCGI: <...> Symbol not found: _PL_curcop <...> Compilation failed in require at /usr/bin/fastcgi-wrapper.pl line 4. I installed FCGI with cpanm so it's up to date. (0.78)

Comment: Hello, the problem turned out to be the missing daemon called fastcgi-wrapper.pl as stated on the instructions page you've given. I've installed a shell script called perl-fcgi on nginx folder and the fastcgi-wrapper.pl on /usr/bin and nginx works with perl now. Problem's solved but if you only post an updated answer I can select it as the solution. Thanks.

Comment: I can't add it to my Answer because that's not the solution the Question you posted; that's the solution to the question you asked in the comments. As for the question you asked in the comments, I answered it almost a month ago. As you just confirmed now, the problem was that you hadn't followed the [instructions](http://nginxlibrary.com/perl-fastcgi/) all the way through.